# How to tell if nginx sites-available is enabled Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04

I'm not too familiar with how Nginx works, but a buddy of mine needed another AWS EC2 instance set up. I noticed it was doing a redirect with Nginx on the main instance and saw that sites-available and sites-enabled were being utilized.

The difference between mine and the main instance is that on AWS console, the sites-available .conf on main is highlighted blue and mine isn't. Does this mean mine is not fully enabled?

I get 0 errors when testing files and reloading nginx. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if it's is highlighted in vim,then if has no effect on nginx,just editor behavior.you should check your sites-enabled folder to see conf in it,if it do not has conf then make a soft link from sites-available to sites-enabled

Comment: I checked and the soft link exists. Maybe i’m missing something else?